# PHP Code Sniffer - WordPress VIP Coding Standards

Tags: security, coding-standards

I'm trying to fix up my code to meet the WordPress VIP Coding Standards. I'm getting a couple of issues that I'd like to see go away, but i'm not sure what the best strategy is.

The first issue is when i'm verifying a nonce while saving metabox data:

```
$nonce = isset( $_POST['revv_meta_box_nonce'] ) ? $_POST['revv_meta_box_nonce'] : '';
```

The error i'm getting here is `'Processing data without nonce verification'`. Which is pretty silly since i'm just storing the nonce in a variable, which I am then verifying on the next line.

The second issue is when i'm storing the data:

```
$foo = isset($_POST['foo']) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['foo'] ) : '';
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_foo', $foo );
```

On the first line there, the sniffer is complaining that i'm not running `wp_unslash` on the data before sanitizing it. But the data is going directly into `update_post_meta` on the next line, which expects that data to *not* be unslashed.

Any ideas on the best strategy for getting rid of these error messages? Thanks!

Comment: since metabox doesn't usually need to have a nounce, I would say that the requirement is idiotic (but that is what the codex show :( ), so your problem is with the VIP people and you should ask them, this is off-topic for this site.

Comment: Agreed, can't see an issue with the first snippet. Second one, you *do* need to unslash (WordPress enforces magic quotes, bizarrely), and the `*_post_meta` functions *do not* expect the data slashed (it will be escaped at point of db insertion).

Comment: @TheDeadMedic thanks, looks like I misread the docs on that one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter_input` to sanitize your `$_POST` array.

```
$nonce = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'revv_meta_box_nonce', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING )
```

use `empty()` to check `$nonce` has a value or not.

You can use the same for second issue

```
$foo = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'foo', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING )
```

change 3rd parameter based on your expected data in `$_POST['foo']`. check this doc for [available filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php).

Comment: this is abusing the limitations of the sniffer instead of fixing the problem. It makes more sense to just turn off the error for that line with a proper comment than hacking around in this way. Who knows, maybe one day the sniffer code will be improved to sniff behind `filter_input`

Comment: VIP it self allow to use in this way as `filter_input` validate or sanitise your data. You only need to pass an appropriate filter for that.

Comment: That is the problem of VIP for allowing bad input that is not properly unslashed, or otherwise sanitized. But I would guess that they allow it because they are not aware of it, not because it is correct code.

Comment: actually seems like the 10up team and the authors of the sniffer are aware of the issue https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/WordPress-Coding-Standards/issues/512